# Bundle install in subdirectory

Tags: ruby, rake, bundle, bundler, sh

I want to setup a rake task that runs 'bundle install' in a subdirectory of the rake file.

```
sh "bundle install -somesortofoption #{DIRECTORY}"
```

I get an error if I do:

```
sh "cd #{DIRECTORY} && bundle install"
```

Any ideas if there is an option in bundler to define the path to run install in? I can't see one?

Thanks

**Update:**

I've also tried this which changes the directory whilst in the rake file:

```
Dir.chdir("#{DIRECTORY}/") do
    sh "bundle install"
end
```

However, this does not seem to call `bundle install` within this directory but in the parent directory, or at least uses the Gemfile from that parent directory. hmm.

**I forgot to say that from the command line if I cd to the directory and `bundle install` it works fine!**

Comment: so what IS the error that you get?

Comment: @phoet Well the error is actually the rakefile failing because the correct gems are not installed. This is because it uses the gemfile from the main project directory and not the subdirectory that it should be using

Comment: are you using rvm or something?

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this exact same problem, and after some digging came across `Bundler.with_clean_env` in this old github ticket https://github.com/carlhuda/bundler/issues/1424, which seems to do exactly what we need:

```
Bundler.with_clean_env { system "cd #{dir} && bundle install" }
```